# Why don't tcp sequence number start from 0?

Tags: tcp

In TCP, one purpose of 3-way-handshake is to exchange initial sequence number for both sides. So why not use 0 instead, and the exchange is not necessary.

That is to say, sequence numbers can be determined without the 3-way-handshake. So connection does not need to be "established" . When received a packet number 0, that just means a new connection.

Are there anything wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.html) states (**emphasis** mine):

> Initial Sequence Number Selection
>
> The protocol places **no restriction on a particular connection being
> used over and over again**.  A connection is defined by a pair of
> sockets.  New instances of a connection will be referred to as
> incarnations of the connection.  The problem that arises from this is
> -- "how does the TCP identify duplicate segments from previous   incarnations of the connection?"  **This problem becomes apparent if the
> connection is being opened and closed in quick succession**, or if the
> connection breaks with loss of memory and is then reestablished.
>
> To avoid confusion **we must prevent segments from one incarnation of
> a   connection from being used while the same sequence numbers may
> still   be present in the network from an earlier incarnation**.  We
> want to   assure this, even if a TCP crashes and loses all knowledge
> of the   sequence numbers it has been using.  When new connections are
> created,   an initial sequence number (ISN) generator is employed
> which selects a   new 32 bit ISN.  The generator is bound to a
> (possibly fictitious) 32   bit clock whose low order bit is
> incremented roughly every 4   microseconds.  Thus, the ISN cycles
> approximately every 4.55 hours.   Since we assume that segments will
> stay in the network no more than   the Maximum Segment Lifetime (MSL)
> and that the MSL is less than 4.55   hours we can reasonably assume
> that ISN's will be unique.
>
> For each connection there is a send sequence number and a receive
> sequence number.  The initial send sequence number (ISS) is chosen by
> the data sending TCP, and the initial receive sequence number (IRS) is
> learned during the connection establishing procedure.
>
> For a connection to be established or initialized, the two TCPs must
> synchronize on each other's initial sequence numbers.  This is done in
> an exchange of connection establishing segments carrying a control bit
> called "SYN" (for synchronize) and the initial sequence numbers.  As a
> shorthand, segments carrying the SYN bit are also called "SYNs".
> Hence, the solution requires a suitable mechanism for picking an
> initial sequence number and a slightly involved handshake to exchange
> the ISN's.